# How to handle less size situation in string concatination?

Tags: c, linux

I'm working on C and want to implements a string concatenation function.
I implemented following function:

```
void mystr_concat(char* dest, char* src)
{
        char* temp = dest;
        while(*temp)
        {
                temp++;
        }

        while(*src)
        {
                *temp++ = *src;
                src++;
        }
        *temp = '\0';
        return;
}
```

The output of above program is that it append "src"  string to "dest" string.

If user passed a "dest" string which is small in the length such that it can't append "src" string anymore.

e.g. user have this strings and invoked function

```
char dest[6] = "abcnd";
char src[100] = "zdfhjksdfskdfsdfsdfj";
mystr_concat(dest, src)
```

In this case
How to check the above raise condition and required solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: You need to pass the max destination size in to your function, or all bets are off. (and unrelated, your second while-loop can simply be `while ((*dst++ = *src++));` and you can throw out the null char set at the end).

Comment: http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=strlcat - basically, do what that function does

Comment: @Dayalrai: Using `sizeof` here is wrong advise. Using `sizeof` on a pointer returns the pointer variable's size, **not** the size of the array that the pointer might reference.

Comment: @Dayalrai: Which array are you referring to, please?

Comment: What would be your preferred approach to solve this? Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that strings, when passed as parameters of functions, are decayed to char pointers. And there is no portable way in *C* to know at runtime the size of a memory zone given by its pointer. So your `mystr_concat` cannot know the size of `dest` (unless you give that size somehow, e.g. by passing that size as an additional function paramter e.g. declaring

```
 void mystr_concat(char* dest, size_t destsize, char* src)
```

Then you might call it with e.g.

```
 char destbuf[36];
 strncpy (destbuf, sizeof(destbuf) /*i.e. 36*/, "start"); 
 mystr_concat(destbuf, sizeof(destbuf), "some-more");
```

Notice that the standard [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) function has a similar convention.

Another possible way is to decide that your function returns a *heap allocated* string and that it is the *responsibility of its caller* to `free` that string. Then you could code

```
char *my_string_catenation (const char* s1, const char* s2)
{
   if (!s1||!s2) return NULL;
   size_t s1len = strlen(s1);
   size_t s2len = strlen(s2);
   char* res = malloc(s1len+s2len+1);
   if (!res) 
    { perror("my_string_catenation malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
   memcpy (res, s1, s1len);
   memcpy (res+s1len, s2, s2len);
   res[s1len+s2len] = (char)0;
   return res;
}
```

You then might code things like

```
 char buf[32];
 snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "+%d", i);
 char* catstr = my_string_catenation((i>30)?"foo":"boo", buf);
 do_something_with(catstr);
 free(catstr), catstr = NULL;
```

<sup>The above example is a bit stupid, since one could just use `snprintf` without `my_string_catenation` but I can't think of a short better example.</sup>

It is common in C libraries to have *conventions* about who is responsible to free some heap-allocated data. You should document such conventions (at least in comments in the header files declaring them).

Perhaps you might be interested in using [Boehm's conservative garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/); you'll then use `GC_MALLOC`  instead of `malloc` etc... and you won't bother about `free` ...

Answer (score 2):

C does not perform any bounds checks on array references. If you need this done, you will need to either pass into the function the maximum size of the destination array and then verify that the source will fit (or decide to truncate it if required), or, introduce an additional data structure to track the length of strings in the way that typical Pascal implementation prefix each string with its maximum length.

Neither solution is automatic and to support this functionality in a safe way requires the use of a language like Java or C# to prevent the use of unsafe constructs.